# I am trying to built strong number program but i am not getting expected output

Tags: java

I am trying to program that whether the no entered by user is strong number or not but i am getting the same output 145=1! + 4!+ 5!=145 is a strong number
123= 1! + 2! + 3!=9 is not a strong number

```java
     import java.util.*;
     public class Strong{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
            int n=s.nextInt();
            int i;
            int fact=1;
            int rem;
            int sum=0;
            int temp=n;
            while(n!=0) {
               rem=n%10;
               for(i=1;i<=rem;i++) {
                  fact=fact*i;
               }
               sum=sum+fact;
               n=n/10;
            }

            if(sum==temp) {
                System.out.println("number u have entered is strong");
            } else {
                System.out.println("no is not strong");
            }
        }
     }
```

For example i have entered no 145 i expect the output number u have entered is strong but actual output is no is not strong

Comment: What is a "strong number"? --- Please format your code properly. --- Please read: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) --- Please create a [MRE]. --- I think I got everything...

Comment: eg 145=1! + 4!+ 5!=145 is a strong number

Comment: 123= 1! + 2! + 3!=9 is not a strong number

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add this information.

Answer (score 2):

You are not resetting your `fact` variable between `while` loops.

Just add `fact = 1;` at the start of the loop, or move the variable declaration `int fact = 1;` inside the loop so it exists only within its scope.

Also, it might be irrelevant to you at this stage, but I'd suggest you to use that chance to learn how to use a debugger; it'll be a great help later.

Comment: It worked thanks but why declaring value of i and fact outside loop code is not working

Comment: What do you mean "why"? This is just how variable scope works in java (and most other languages).Unless you reset the variable, it retains the value it had on previous loop iteration. See https://www.baeldung.com/java-variable-scope for example.

Answer (score 0):

Move `int fact = 1;` inside the loop. this is not getting reset.